# How is a product defined in the word 'product backlog' in scrum?

Tags: scrum

Does it map to an application 1-1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Answer (score 4):

### "Application" Isn't a Scrum Term

The term "application" doesn't have a specific meaning in Scrum. It sounds like you are using it the way Scrum uses the term Product. In Scrum, Product means the same as the regular use of the word product - something that you sell. In Scrum, a Product has a Product Owner.

### Product Backlog is all the Product Features that People Have Asked For

There's a nice article [here](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/scrum/product-backlog) that tells that a Product Backlog is:

> the master list of all functionality desired in the product

and goes on to describe how items are moved from the Product Backlog to the current Sprint Backlog:

> The product owner shows up at the sprint planning meeting with the prioritized product backlog and describes the top items to the team. The team then determines which items they can complete during the coming sprint. The team then moves items from the Product Backlog to the  Sprint Backlog.

This is repeated each sprint with the current prioritization of the Product Backlog. And from elsewhere on the same site, here is the contrast between Product Backlog and Sprint Backlog:

> ...the product backlog is a list of desired features for the product. The sprint backlog is a list of tasks to be completed in a sprint.

Finally, an important point is:

> The Product Backlog is then allowed to grow and change as more is learned about the product and its customers.

Answer (score 1):

It maps to whatever you plan to release.

Comment: +1: Don't fetishize over "Product" or "Application".  Focus on "release". The "Product Backlog" could be called "Backlog of features required to build a complete product".

Answer (score 1):

Product Backlog is so called to differentiate from the Sprint Backlogs.

Product Backlog is a list of work to be done, preferably defined in a way that focuses on user experience with whatever is being built (hence the prominence of user stories as a way to write backlog items). It can map to a software application (or, to be more precise, its functionality) if that is what you build with Scrum in your project.

Sprint Backlog is a list of work team commits to in a given sprint. It consists of Product Backlog items moved there and tasks describing more or less what work the team plans to perform to deliver each of the backlog items.

*BTW - I think reading a book on Scrum or attending a training would do you good.*

Answer (score 0):

The Scrum definition of product, is the software developed or the system being developed itself.